# Fastest way to Compare two Dictionaries using foreach and .contains to find unique and non-unique data

Tags: c#, dictionary

I currently have 2 dictionaries with ard 30,000keys.

I am currently using two foreach loops to find the unique keys in dict1. And I write the unique keys in dict2 to another dictionary(3).

If the keys match i perform a check to see if the value are the same. And print if they are not the same.

Is it better to use foreach, it seems to be affecting the performance. Is there any other faster solution or built in functions? Ir shd I try the dict.contains method.

---

```
Dict1                    Dict2

Keys    Values           Keys     Values        
S0111   00000            S0000    00010
S0000   00010            S0020    00015
S0020   00015            S0040    00150
S0040   00200            S0050    00250
```

---

```
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> sourceRow in sourceData)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> dumpRow in dumpData)
            {
                // A in C, skip
                if (sourceRow.Key == dumpRow.Key)
                {
                    Is_Unique_Address = false;

                    if (sourceRow.Value != dumpRow.Value)
                    {
                        Data_Mismatch_Criteria(sourceRow.Key, sourceRow.Value, dumpRow.Key, dumpRow.Value);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by finding the unique keys, the keys in Dictionary are always Unique!

Comment: It's not clear. All keys in the dictionary are always unique. Provide code sample here.

Comment: i think unique means in this case: keys that are in the dict, but not in the other dict

Comment: I mean unique as in keys in dictionary 1 vs keys in dictionary 2. And keys in dict2 that are not in dict1.

Comment: A code sample might be helpful for others to be able to help you.

Comment: it has no sense then to compare keys "If the keys match". How it can match if they are different by definition?

Comment: I will post it shortly.

Comment: There are keys that match and some keys that dont match

Comment: I can't understand you. Describe it in more precision way or paste here code sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> sourceRow in sourceData)
{
    string dumpValue;

    if (dumpData.TryGetValue(sourceRow.Key, out dumpValue) && dumpValue != sourceRow.Value)
    {
        Data_Mismatch_Criteria(sourceRow.Key, sourceRow.Value, sourceRow.Key, dumpValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks goods. 1qn. why do we use out dumpValue?

Is this faster than using dumpData.Contains(sourceRow.key, out dumpValue)?

Answer (score 5):

This code enables you to select keys from dict2, which are not contained in dict1.

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// Add data to both dictionaries

var uniqueKeys = dict2.Keys.Except(dict1.Keys);
```

Is that what you need?

EDIT: Please note, that the code above selects all keys from dict2 not contained in dict1. If you need to check that both dictionaries have different sets of keys (and I assume that it **may be** the case), then you can use:

```
var areTheSame = dict2.Keys.Any(x => !dict1.ContainsKey(x))
|| dict1.Keys.Any(x => !dict2.ContainsKey(x));
```

EDIT 2: After OP edit, I now know what you need:

```
var differentValues = dict2.Where(pair => dict1.ContainsKey(pair.Key))
     .Select(pair => new
     {
         ValueA = pair.Value,
         ValueB = dict1[pair.Key],
         Key = pair.Key
     })
     .Where(x => x.ValueA != x.ValueB)
     .ToList();

foreach (var differentValue in differentValues)
{
    Console.WriteLine(differentValue);
}
```

Comment: I need to extract this information. Keys only in dict1, keys only on dict 2. Keys in both dict1 and dict 2 but their values mismatch

Comment: @Manick9 OK, look if this fits.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this LINQ query will return dictionary of records that either are not presented in both dictionaries or has different values :

```
var dictOfUniqueValues =
     dict1.Where(kv => !dict2.ContainsKey(kv.Key)).Concat(
         dict2.Where(kv => !dict1.ContainsKey(kv.Key) || dict1[kv.Key] != kv.Value))
    .ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
```

Well let's take a closer look of what's going on here :

```
var dictOfUniqueValues =

     // get records from dict1 that don't exist in dict2 by comparing keys
     dict1.Where(kv => !dict2.ContainsKey(kv.Key)).Concat(

     // get records from dict2 that don't exist in dict1 by comparing keys
     // and records that do exist, but values are not equal
         dict2.Where(kv => !dict1.ContainsKey(kv.Key) || dict1[kv.Key] != kv.Value))

     // convert the resulting IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T1, T2>> to dictionary
    .ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
```

Comment: I find it quite hard to understand as a beginner.